# Divert background color choosing in p5js

Tags: javascript, random, colors, background, draw

I'm a noobie, so please be kind to me :)

I'm putting together a p5js script. Background color is random, choosing from an array with values for black or white background. Drawing color is also random.

It works fine most of the times, but from now and then I get a color that can't really be appreciated from the background, so the question is, is there a way in which I can vary the background resulting color depending on the color of the draw? How would I go about discerning what combination is "perceivable" and which one isn't?

Comment: Just create an array of suitable darker colors for a white background and one of sufficiently bright colors for a black background, then pick randomly from the proper array depending on the background choice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could just round the background value so they differentiate more:

```
background(roundTo(random(250),10));

function roundTo(val, num){
 return round(val / num) * num;
}
```